# Notifications appearing even if they have been viewed

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, notifications, sync, email

I just switched to my first Android phone (been an iPhone user until now), running Lollipop 5.0 on a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact, and I am having a strange issue.

If I receive messages on Facebook Messenger or emails on Outlook.com and view them on my PC, while my phone is not connected to the internet, these emails and messages should be marked as "read".  When I next connect my phone to the internet (even if it is hours after I would have read these emails and Facebook messages), I get notifications of the emails on my phone, and a notification for each message in the Facebook Messenger conversation.  The phone keeps sending notifications for literally each email and each message which would have been received and seen on the PC.

Does anyone know what is causing this? I did not have this issue on my iPhone and it is really annoying me.

Comment: I can't say for Facebook Messenger, but I also experienced the same issue on Outlook. I can only guess that this is a problem with how they developed their apps. Perhaps they store read status on the device locally, not synced to the server, hence the difference between browser and mobile app.

Comment: I see - so it's likely an app-related issue then?

Comment: Yes, it's an app-related issue. AFAIK, there's nothing wrong with your phone (as well as mine).

Comment: Thanks - I've only experienced this with those two apps, so it looks like it.